# Materials UI Datatable - Using icons and extra data in dataset but not at cost of sorting

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is what I want to achieve using Materials UI Datatables. The cell must have an icon to indicate the gain or fall of the cost. Moreover, the icon must be in red or green color alongwith the keyword which caused the increase or decrease.

```
+-------------------+ 
|  Cost             | 
+-------------------+ 
|  ▲ $10 (used-cars)| 
+-------------------+ 
|  ▼ $14 (new-cars) | 
+-------------------+
```

I can use the following MUI code. It seems to work, but the column is not sortable anymore.

```
const columns = [
  {
    name: "cost",
    label: "Cost",
    options: {
      filter: true,
      customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
        return (
          value.icon + ' ' + value.price + '('+ value.keyword + ')'
        );
      }
    }
  }
];

const data = [
  { cost: {icon: 'up', price: 10, keyword: 'used-cars' } },
  { cost: {icon: 'down', price: 14, keyword: 'new-cars' } }
]

<MUIDataTable
  title={"Cost List"}
  data={data}
  columns={columns}
  options={{filters: true}}
/>
```

What could be the proper way to achieve this? I am using ReactJS and mui-datatables library

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using `customSort`. Here's how:

```
<MUIDataTable
  title={"Cost List"}
  data={data}
  columns={columns}
  options={{
    filters: true, 
    customSort: (data, colIndex, order) => {  
      return data.sort((a, b) => { 
        if(colIndex === 1) {
          return (a.data[colIndex].price < b.data[colIndex].price ? -1: 1 ) * (order === 'desc' ? 1 : -1);
        } 
        return (a.data[colIndex] < b.data[colIndex] ? -1: 1 ) * (order === 'desc' ? 1 : -1);
      });
    }

  }}
/>
```